# How do you enable customers to log in to your site using their Google account?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, openid

I just saw http://uservoice.com/login. It uses Google accounts, [Myspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myspace), Yahoo, [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) and all to sign in customers into its site? Can I do that?

I mean, customers need not register to my site. They can just sign in with their accounts on the above sites.

If you've a solution, I'd prefer a PHP and MySQL based one.

Answer (score 15):

See here: [Google Login PHP Class](http://www.andrewpeace.com/php-google-login-class.html).

Also be sure to refer to the [Google Federated Login site](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look at this too: https://rpxnow.com/ - it will only need integrating at the HTML/javascript level.

It's what http://uservoice.com/login appears to use.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at the OpenID Enablded PHP library (http://www.openidenabled.com/php-openid/).

This should play pretty nicely with any LAMP installation without needing to use Zend.

Answer (score 2):

[Zend_OpenId](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.html) from [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/)

> Zend_OpenId is a Zend Framework component that provides a simple API for building OpenID-enabled sites and identity providers.

Answer (score 1):

http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/

Answer (score 1):

Uservoice users RPX  http://rpxnow.com .   You can easily use it with PHP, just https and parse the json or xml repsonse.   You don't even need to change your database schema or store anything locally.

Answer (score -1):

i think is good solution for you
 step by step

1-download [openid](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/blobs/raw/master/openid.php)

2-create file called login.php like this (in same directory or change require_one to your own ) :

```
<?php
require_once 'openid.php';
$myopenid = new LightOpenID("your-domain.com");//no problem even if u can write http://localhost

if ($myopenid->mode) {
    if ($myopenid->mode == 'cancel') {
        echo "User has canceled authentication !";
    } elseif($myopenid->validate()) {
        $data = $myopenid->getAttributes();
        $email = $data['contact/email'];
        $first = $data['namePerson/first'];
        echo "Identity : $openid->identity <br>";
        echo "Email : $email <br>";
        echo "First name : $first";
    } else {
        echo "The user has not logged in";
    }
} else {
    echo "Go to index page to log in.";
}
?>
```

3-next is about creating file called  index.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'openid.php';
$openid = new LightOpenID("your-domain.com");//no problem even if u can write http://localhost

$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
$openid->required = array(
  'namePerson/first',
  'namePerson/last',
  'contact/email',
);
$openid->returnUrl = 'your-domain.com/login.php'
?>



<a href="<?php echo $openid->authUrl() ?>">Login with Google</a>
```

i almost forgot for log out u can kill session;