# How to build a login system with other sites' account?

Tags: php, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you enable customers to login to your site using their google account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479535/how-do-you-enable-customers-to-login-to-your-site-using-their-google-account)

I want to create a login system with other sites' account such as google,yahoo,facebook. stackoverflow.com has same login system,too. Using php script, how can it be possible to create that login system?

Comment: http://openid.net/add-openid/

Answer (score 1):

You can try OpenId API. Check this link-  http://openid.net/get-an-openid/start-using-your-openid/ or use API for various available services as suggested.